# Videocalls/conferencing with the Pi4B 4gb model?

Tags: video, streaming-video, pi-4, raspbian-buster

so I'm currently looking for a way to do two way video calls between the pi and an android device but most of the solutions I can find for this are from tutorials or software that is either not maintained or unavailable anymore.

The major goal is to call the Pi (from an android app), automatically accept the call and respond with the a USB-camera video and audio without any interaction/buttonpress.

Initially thought of using Google Duo however there's no api available for that making automatic answering of calls impossible. Afaik Skype is also not an option. Currently using meet.jis.ti however that requires the video room to be out at all times on the raspberry pi which isnt ideal since I would like it to do other things like act as a calendar.

So any suggested solutions to this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!